spring security oauth2 client authorization code flow
I do have spring boot application using thymeleaf as a template engine. I need to secure this client application by using the Authorization Code Flow according to OAuth 2.0 RFC 6749.
However i do have the problem that spring seems to want a user-info-uri (which is not specified in RFC 6749). So i am getting this error:
[missing_user_info_uri] Missing required UserInfo Uri in UserInfoEndpoint for Client Registration: custom 
My configuration looks like this:
security:
 oauth2:
  client:
    registration:
      custom:
        client-id: <my-client-id>
        client-secret: asdasd
        authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
        scope: email
        client-authentication-method: client_secret_post
    provider:
      custom:
          authorization-uri: <my-auth-url>
          token-uri: <my-token-url>

The config i am using is this:
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults()).oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
  }

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

It is very hard to go over the docs, because on multiple sites they mention different things. The authorization server is a custom implementation, but i don't know the exact implementation. Using Postman, the auth server works, so that is not the problem.
What do i have to configure, so that OAuth2 and not Open ID Connect is supported?

I think since you have email in scope it wants to hit the user-info endpoint to get that information. Did you try just putting openid in the scope?

yes i did try that. also when i dont specify a scope at all, it doesnt change.

Well, I disagree. I tried it and it hits userinfo when I add email scope and it doesn't when I only have openid scope. You should probably double check your testing. I was using Auth0.com.

The thing is, that i don't want a scope at all. when i use openid it seems to work, but then Spring expects an id_token but the server only sends access_token, which is correct. I then changed my redirect-uri to redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/authorized/{registrationId}" and now it seems that the browser gets redirected to `{requestedUrl}?continue after the auth flow, but then gets into a TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS_ERROR

you arae using Oauth2Login, if you read the docs, it clearly states The OAuth 2.0 Login feature lets an application have users log in to the application by using their existing account at an OAuth 2.0 Provider (such as GitHub) or OpenID Connect 1.0 Provider (such as Google). OAuth 2.0 Login implements two use cases: “Login with Google” or “Login with GitHub”. What you want to use is the neutral https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/index.html Oauth2 Client if you are authenticating against something custom.
